# symfony2 form not valid and no errors

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the following controller:

```
public function postStuffAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add("name", "text")
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        return $form->isValid(); //False
        //return $form->getErrorsAsString(); //No errors
    }
```

This is my form:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://mydomain/resource/1?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=appointmed">
     <input type="text" name="name" />
     <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"> Upload file </button>
 </form>
```

This form lives in a different domain, it is not redenred as a twig template, is just a plain html form.

When the controller gets the request the form is always empty, what could be happenning?

Comment: What you mean with `this form lives in a different domain`? I see the action to another domain but I don't see why you build the form on the controller and try to validate it using `handleRequest` since that form it's not a Symfony2 form is just "another form" try to get the request as for example `$request->get('name')` and see if it has values and values are valid or something other way to go

Answer (score 2):

You can only use use FormBuilder's built in validation function if you are creating the form and presenting it in Twig.

If you want to validate input from a manually built form or a form posted from another domain then you need to access the Request object, map it to your entity and then call the validator service. For example:

```
// Setup entity and map Request
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setName($request->get('name', null));

// Validate the entity
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($entity);
if (count($errors) > 0) {           
    return $errors
}
```

Comment: okay, but I'm not able to get the data sent from the client, whenever y print `$request->request->all()` I always get null.

Comment: What do you see if you just dump the whole $request object instead of using $request->request->all()?